# How to get an ID from an URL using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

#### Problem

I am currently doing a `preg_match` on an url. This url has a certain id in the second parameter or the third parameter. However I don't know how I could get this more efficiently.

#### Code

```
preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id);
if (!isset($id[1])) {
    preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/thing/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id);
    if (!isset($id[1])) {
        preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/other/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id);
        if (!isset($id[1])) {
            preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/thingelse/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id);
            if (!isset($id[1])) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### What I would like to do

```
if (preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id)) {
    $id = $id[1];
} else if (preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/(.+?)/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id)) {
    $id = $id[1];
} else {
    return false;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So much code can just be replaced by using `parse_url` function

Comment: Use `parse_url`.  Regexes are not a magic wand that you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings, especially if the problem is a common one that already has code written, tested and debugged to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the following regular expressions in fact did work as you wanted them to

```
if (preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id)) {
    $id = $id[1];
} else if (preg_match('~http://www.example.com/some/(.+?)/(.+?)/~is', $url, $id)) {
    $id = $id[1];
} else {
    return false;
}
```

... then you would never reach the second case anyway. The match will already be made in the first RegEx, as the beginning or the second expression is identical to the first expression. And even if you turned them around you would always get the id from the first parameter/path part, as you set `$id = $id[1]` on both results.

As stated in the comments, you probably would be better off using `parse_url` for this instead:

```
$urls = [
    'http://www.example.com/some/thingelse/foo/bar/baz/',
    'http://www.example.com/some/foo/bar/baz/',
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo "Checking $url", PHP_EOL;

    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $parts = explode('/', $path);

    echo "Second parameter: ", $parts[2], PHP_EOL;
    echo "Third parameter:  ", $parts[3], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Checking http://www.example.com/some/thingelse/foo/bar/baz/
Second parameter: thingelse
Third parameter:  foo

Checking http://www.example.com/some/foo/bar/baz/
Second parameter: foo
Third parameter:  bar
```

Comment: What's the difference between just exploding on `/` and using `parse_url` first?

Comment: Maybe not so much for your implementation, but using `parse_url` you will only get actual path parts (parameters) in `$parts`, avoiding irrelevant ones (`"http", "", "www.example.com''`) and they will be easily accessible with the first param as `$parts[1]`, second at `$parts[2]` etc. Also, if you would like to look from the end, e.g. getting the last parameter, it will not break with URL:s like `http://www.example.com/some/thingelse/foo/bar/baz/?hours=24/7`